# Checking different codnitions for 2 array wheater its empty or not

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-if

I have two arrays say X and Y. I need to check conditions as below

```
if ((!x_array && x_array.length == 0) && (!y_array && y_array.length == 0)) {
    console.log("======BOTH EMPTY======")
    //display something
}
if ((x_array && x_array.length > 0) && (y_array && y_array.length > 0)) {
    console.log("======BOTH NOT EMPTY======")
    // do something
} 
if ((x_array && x_array.length > 0) && (!y_array && y_array.length == 0)) {
    console.log("======ONE IS EMPTY AND OTHER IS NOT======")
    //do something
}

if ((!x_array && x_array.length == 0) && (y_array && y_array.length > 0)) {
    console.log("======ONE IS EMPTY AND OTHER IS NOT======")
    //do something 
} 
else {
     //do something here

}
```

I checked with both `OR` and `AND` but nothing is working as needed. Please help

Comment: Btw, which test case is not working?

Comment: @gurvinder372, by the looks of it, I would go with the first one just **won't** execute ever.

Comment: @ekta I see you made an edit to my code to verify 'undefined' scenario; do u want that handled as well cos in your problem statement, I see only empty or not.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Test case is if i check for either one array for null is where i am facing issue. IF both array is not null its works as per ur answer but if any one array is null than arise the issue

Comment: @ekta Did you tried my answer?

Comment: @ekta see if this helps your issue .. https://jsfiddle.net/v4boac79/

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes i tried but no luck :(

Comment: @ekta Which part/test-case didn't work?

Comment: @ekta I have added a demo, all 4 test cases work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can't work. Let me point out the flaws for you.

```
!x_array && x_array.length == 0
```

This line can **never** evaluate to true if `x_array` is not defined or is null since `null` and `undefined` are "falsy" types. Because of that, `false && true` and `false && false` are never true. So, the first condition can't execute. A better way to write this would be:

```
...
if( ( !x_array ) || ( !y_array ) ) {
    console.log( 'Either array is either undefined or null' );
}
```

Then, you can go on to check values by using the `length` property to see if they are **defined** *but* empty.

```
...
if( ( x_array.length === 0 ) || ( y_array.length === 0 ) ) {
    console.log( 'Either array is empty' );
}
```

You can apply similar logic to find out the next few conditions for your code.

P.S.: It's a general stylistic preference to use `camelCase` in JavaScript. And try using the `===` operator when comparing values. The `===` can be rewritten as:

```
return ( typeof objA == typeof objB ) && ( objA == objB );
```

Since `==` **only** checks if values are equal and **not** the types.

The following is true: `'2' == 2`.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination:). I tried your method. the issue i am facing is 
if(x_array || x_array.length > 0){
} 
its say length of undefined

Comment: Those conditions were given just as an example. If you want a full example, I would be glad to write a small snippet for you.

Comment: Also condition wrote for either one array is null is showing false 
`if (((x_array && x_array.length > 0) && (y_array && y_array.length === 0)) || ((x_array && x_array.length === 0) && (y_array && y_array.length > 0))) { }`

Comment: @ekta, I have written an example for you to go through. Take a look here https://jsbin.com/wuhomavuse/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @ekta, then please accept this answer and we can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify with some refactored code!

```
var isEmp = (input) => !input || input.length == 0;
```

And this use this as

```
if ( isEmp ( x_array ) && isEmp( y_array )
{
   console.log( "both empty" );
}
else if ( !isEmp ( x_array ) && !isEmp( y_array )
{
   console.log( "both not empty" );
}
else
{
   console.log( "One of them is empty other is full" );
}
```

Or even simpler

```
var isXEmpty = isEmp( x_Array );
var isYEmpty = isEmp( y_Array );

var log = isXEmpty ? ( isYEmpty ? "Both Empty" : "Only X Empty" ) : ( isYEmpty ? "Only Y Empty" : "Both not Empty" );
```

**Demo**

```js
console.log( "1", checkArrays( [], [] )); 
console.log( "2", checkArrays( [1], [1] )); 
console.log( "3", checkArrays( [1], [] )); 
console.log( "4", checkArrays( [], [1] )); 

function checkArrays( x_Array, y_Array ) 
{
  var isEmp = (input) => !input || input.length == 0;

  var isXEmpty = isEmp(x_Array);
  var isYEmpty = isEmp(y_Array);

  return isXEmpty ? (isYEmpty ? "Both Empty" : "Only X Empty") : (isYEmpty ? "Only Y Empty" : "Both not Empty");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the ! in the some of your conditions is the culprit;

I also merged two of your conditions to avoid repetition.

```js
let x_array = ['1'];
let y_array = ['1'];

if ((x_array && x_array.length == 0) && (y_array && y_array.length == 0)) {
    console.log("======BOTH EMPTY======")
    //display something
}
if ((x_array && x_array.length > 0) && (y_array && y_array.length > 0)) {
    console.log("======BOTH NOT EMPTY======")
    // do something
} 
if (((x_array && x_array.length > 0) && (y_array && y_array.length == 0)) || ((x_array && x_array.length == 0) && (y_array && y_array.length > 0))) {
    console.log("======ONE IS EMPTY AND OTHER IS NOT======")
    //do something
}
else {
     //do something here

}
```

Comment: The parity check in each sub case is redundant, though.

Comment: @weirdpanda please elaborate

Comment: `x_array && ...` along with `y_array && ... ` can be reduced down to a single return-base check like `if( !x_array || !y_array )...`